# Force iSCSI Disconnect

Tags: windows, windows-10, freenas, iscsi

I've been toying around with iSCSI for a little while (FreeNAS 11.1-U5 target, Win10 Pro initiator) and have run into what would be a bit of a deal-breaking issue: I can't seem to disconnect from an iSCSI target, regardless of what I try. All methods get a *"The session cannot be logged out since a device on that session is currently being used"* message, and fail to disconnect.

What I've tried:

- Clicking **Disconnect** in the iSCSI Initiator panel
- Running the equivalent command in PowerShell
- Taking the disk **offline** in Disk Management first
- Disabling the **Microsoft iSCSI Initiator** device in Device Manager (requires a reboot, not tenable)
- **Turning the iSCSI service off** in FreeNAS (this works eventually, but I'd like to not have to do it this way, if I can help it)
- Per other sources, I've removed all **favorite targets** and **target portals** in the iSCSI properties dialog.

The extent is not currently initiated in Windows, and therefore does not have a file system (so, if I understand correctly, cannot be accessed by the OS in a way that would hold the connection open).

My preferred behavior would be to disconnect on request (or at least, successfully force disconnect), so I can then connect from another machine, and then back again when necessary.

Thanks in advance for any ideas!

---

Hardware Details:

**Win10 Pro System** (desktop): Ryzen 5 1600X, 16GB RAM, NVMe boot drive, Mellanox ConnectX-2 (direct connection to server)

**FreeNAS System** (server): Core i3-4170, 32GB RAM, 4×10TB in RAIDZ2, Mellanox ConnectX-2 (direct connection to desktop)

Comment: If your task manager is opened, maybe you should try to close your task manager, the `disk performance` page of the task manager is occupying the iSCSI device, which causes the iSCSI device to fail disconnection.

Answer (score 0):

@0xAA55 answer fixed this for me.

- Close task manager.
- Close disk management snapin.